# Where can I find Google App Engine API for Java release notes

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm running an old version of `appengine-api-1.0-sdk` (`1.9.54`) and want to upgrade to a newer version (1.9.90), but I can't find any list of changes from one version to the next. I would have expected a release note or something in the download, but it just points me to a general Java page for Appengine: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/release-notes. This doesn't tell me what has changed from one version of the SDK to the next.
Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can use BigQuery to select different points between 2 versions

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=google_cloud_release_notes&t=release_notes&page=table&_ga=2.107183563.811335336.1632571946-1193389554.1631929347

Comment: @TimCobra please consider accepting this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks